# specializing a template on bool + integral + floating-point return types

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to write a function template which returns a random variable of various types (bool, char, short, int, float, double, along with unsigned versions of these).

I couldn't see how to do this using the latest C++11 standard library, since I need to use either uniform_int_distribution or uniform_real_distribution. I thought I could specialize the template:

```
template<typename T>
T randomPrimitive() { std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dst; std::mt19937 rng; return dst(rng); }

template<>
bool randomPrimitive<bool>() { std::uniform_int_distribution<signed char> dst; std::mt19937 rng; return dst(rng) >= 0 ? true : false; }

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type randomPrimitive() { std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dst; std::mt19937 rng; return dst(rng); }
```

Under Visual Studio 2012 Update 3, this gives:

error C2668: '`anonymous-namespace'::randomPrimitive' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

when I try to compile:

```
randomPrimitive<float>();
```

Is there a way to specialize a function template so I can write three different implementations for bool, other integral types, and floating-point types?

Comment: syntax error - see my answer

Comment: are you sure you want to create another instance of the RNG for each function call? usually you would create a RNG instance and use it for many calls (each generating another random number).

Comment: In this case it was preferable for me to avoid keeping state and simply instantiate a new RNG every time.

Comment: By the way, the specialization for `bool` should use `bernoulli_distribution()`. Your version always returns `true`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're getting close with your edits.  You need to restrict your "integral" version to integral types.  That will get rid of the ambiguity:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if
<
    std::is_integral<T>::value,
    T
>::type
randomPrimitive()
```

But if you run it now with something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << randomPrimitive<float>() << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << randomPrimitive<double>() << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << (int)randomPrimitive<signed char>() << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << randomPrimitive<unsigned>() << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << randomPrimitive<bool>() << '\n';
}
```

You'll get something like:

```
0.814724
0.814724
0.814724
0.814724
0.814724
0.814724
0.814724
0.814724
0.814724
0.814724
0.135477
0.135477
0.135477
0.135477
0.135477
0.135477
0.135477
0.135477
0.135477
0.135477
92
92
92
92
92
92
92
92
92
92
3499211612
3499211612
3499211612
3499211612
3499211612
3499211612
3499211612
3499211612
3499211612
3499211612
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Getting there, but not exactly random.  The problem is that you are constructing a new engine every time you use it.  What you want is to create a URNG once, and then keep getting random bits out of it:

```
std::mt19937&
get_eng()
{
    static std::mt19937 eng;
    return eng;
}
```

And you should really only create your distributions once too.  Most of them are stateless, but not all of them.  Best just to assume all of them carry state, and you don't want to throw that state away.

```
static std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dst;
```

This will greatly improve things, but you're not there yet:

```
0.814724
0.135477
0.905792
0.835009
0.126987
0.968868
0.913376
0.221034
0.632359
0.308167
0.547221
0.188382
0.992881
0.996461
0.967695
0.725839
0.98111
0.109862
0.798106
0.297029
92
13
49
122
46
7
105
45
43
8
2816384844
3427077306
153380495
1551745920
3646982597
910208076
4011470445
2926416934
2915145307
1712568902
0
1
1
1
1
0
1
0
1
0
```

I note that all 10 of the values from `signed char` are positive.  That doesn't look right.  It turns out that `std::uniform_int_distribution` has a constructor that looks like this:

```
explicit uniform_int_distribution(IntType a = 0,
                                  IntType b = numeric_limits<IntType>::max());
```

I'm guessing that's not what you want, so:

```
static std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dst(std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), 
                                            std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
```

And finally, if you want a random `bool`, go with the `std::bernoulli_distribution`.

Putting this all together:

```
#include <random>

std::mt19937&
get_eng()
{
    static std::mt19937 eng;
    return eng;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if
<
    std::is_integral<T>::value,
    T
>::type
randomPrimitive()
{
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dst(std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), 
                                                std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
    return dst(get_eng());
}

template<>
bool
randomPrimitive<bool>()
{
    static std::bernoulli_distribution dst;
    return dst(get_eng());
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if
<
    std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
    T
>::type
randomPrimitive()
{
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dst;
    return dst(get_eng());
}

#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << randomPrimitive<float>() << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << randomPrimitive<double>() << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << (int)randomPrimitive<signed char>() << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << randomPrimitive<unsigned>() << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << randomPrimitive<bool>() << '\n';
}
```

Which for me outputs:

```
0.814724
0.135477
0.905792
0.835009
0.126987
0.968868
0.913376
0.221034
0.632359
0.308167
0.547221
0.188382
0.992881
0.996461
0.967695
0.725839
0.98111
0.109862
0.798106
0.297029
92
13
-79
-6
46
-121
-23
45
43
8
2816384844
3427077306
153380495
1551745920
3646982597
910208076
4011470445
2926416934
2915145307
1712568902
0
1
1
1
1
0
1
0
1
0
```

And if this still isn't outputting what you intended, hopefully you've got enough direction to take it from here.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this out and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your detailed assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You do not specialize (with the exception of full specialization), you overload function templates. Overloading only works on parameter types, never on result type. And as your function template does not take any parameters there is no way for overload resolution to decide what to pick for you.

You either have to specify template parameters in this case or try to use conversion operator:

```
struct RandomPrimitive
{
    operator float()
    {
        // your float implementation here
    }

    operator int()
    {
        // your int implementation here
    }

    // more operator type() as needed
};

RandomPrimitive randomPrimitive;

float f = randomPrimitive;
int i = randomPrimitive;
```

Comment: I was hoping to write just three implementations, as in my example in the question. With conversion operators I think I'd have to write a separate conversion operator for every supported type (bool, char, unsigned char, int, float double, etc)? Specifying template parameters is fine, but I still can't get randomPrimitive<float>() to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for template specialization is incorrect.  Try this instead:

```
template<>
bool randomPrimitive<bool>()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<signed char> dst;
    std::mt19937 rng;
    return dst(rng) >= 0;
}
```

The difference is in the `<bool>` between the function name, `randomPrimitive`, and the parameter list, `()`.

---

The type `char` may be either `unsigned char` or `signed char` - it's up to the compiler. Your implementation clearly depends on `char` being interpreted as `signed char`, so you should make that explicit.

Also, the expression `x ? true : false` where `x` is a `bool` expression is identical to simply `x`.

Comment: Thanks for the fix - your version compiles for me as well. I think the 'ambiguous call to overloaded function' error is coming from ambiguity between the other two declarations though, so it doesn't allow randomPrimitive<float>() to compile.

Comment: Aha good point @Timothy, I changed it to "signed char". The x ? true : false is just a stylistic preference.